# Parallel edges are merged into 1 when using splines = true in graphviz

Tags: graphviz, spline, dot, edge-detection

I'm using graphviz (dot) to generate an undirected multigraph where a lot of the edges are overlapping with nodes and I also have to parallel edges (2 nodes with multiple edges).

I tried to use splines = true to remove the overlap but that just made a ton of parallel edges merge into a single edge.

Here is a Picture on my graph with and without splines:

[using splines = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkYAO.png)

[using splines = false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q42ZG.png)

What I am looking to get would be a way to visualize the parallel edges without having to compromise with graph clarity.

I replicated this issue with a smaller graph:

[using splines = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxBsy.png)

[using splines = false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL98T.png)

Here is the dot code for this smaller graph:

```
graph G {
    bgcolor = grey
    layout = fdp
    outputorder = edgesfirst
    splines = false
    
    
    a [color = white, style = filled, shape = circle ]
    b [color = white, style = filled, shape = circle ]
    b [color = white, style = filled, shape = circle ]
    c [color = white, style = filled, shape = circle ]
    d [color = white, style = filled, shape = circle ]
    e [color = white, style = filled, shape = circle ]
    f [color = white, style = filled, shape = circle ]
    g [color = white, style = filled, shape = circle ]
    h [color = white, style = filled, shape = circle ];

    a--b [color=red]
    a--b [color=blue]
    a--g [color=red]
    a--f [color=blue]
    a--c [color=black]
    a--d [color=red]
    b--h [color=black]
    e--h [color=blue]
    e--d [color=black]
    e--g [color=red]
    c--f [color=black]
    c--f [color=red]
    b--d [color=blue]
    g--b [color=black]
    h--a [color=red]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting a bug, introduced sometime after version 2.43.0.  It seems to affect every engine except **dot**.
I suggest reporting this bug here: https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues.
No work-arounds found, yet.

Answer (score 1):

- your example graph is minimally missing a closing brace.  Not sure if any nodes or edges are missing
- your graph is actually using the **fdp** engine, not the **dot** engine `layout = fdp`
- aesthetics are often in the eye of the beholder, but here are some suggestions:

  - try different layout engines (**dot, neato, circo, twopi**)
  - also try **splines** = *polyline* and *curved*
  - look at coloring the parallel edges (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html)

Comment: I have tried a lot of varying combinations to no success the issue really lies in the parallel edges, fdp layout, neato layout, different splines, nothing helps me get the parallel edges to separate. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173764/what-is-the-best-way-to-draw-large-graph-using-graphvis?rq=1
In this post they have visualisations that seem to have parallel edges using splines but even coping their code, I have different results.

Comment: Note that the linked SO post is years old, before the bug was introduced.  Ubuntu (Linux) still seems to provide version 2.43.0 - pre-bug.